# Segmentation fault with any tcl api (Tcl_*) used in my environment in windows

Tags: c++, c, dll, tcl

I have a dll which is linked to tcl static library (`tcl84tsx.lib`). Now When it is required , i am dynamicly loading this dll from my exe . My exe calls some functions of dll  , and those functions of dll is calling functions of tcl library.

I am getting segmentation fault for any tcl function called from dll.

Following is part of code of dll which first calls `Tcl` function:

```
if (mTclInterp == NULL) {
    mTclInterp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
    Tcl_Init(mTclInterp);
}
```

Here i am creating `Tcl interpreter` in C++ by calling  `Tcl_CreatInterp`  function of `tcl library`. I am getting `segmentation` fault at this line. Note that everything is working fine in `linux` but i am getting this issue in windows.

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you call `Tcl_FindExecutable`?

Comment: Tcl 8.4 isn't supported any more.

Comment: Bear in mind also that Tcl interpreters **must not** be passed between threads. This is because they use lots of thread-specific variables internally so as to avoid needing global locks, so it isn't something that it is practical to hack around.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I added different initialization api like Tcl_FindExecutable , Tcl_Preserve , Tcl_SetRecursionLimit , Tcl_ResetResult  and it solved the problem. Thanks every one who took out sometime and humble enough to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first call into the Tcl library should be to `Tcl_FindExecutable` *or* to `Tcl_Main` (when you want what that does; pretty much the first thing it does inside is call `Tcl_FindExecutable`). The call to `Tcl_FindExecutable` initialises the library itself, especially in relation to the memory management and filesystem access layers.

Once the library is initialised, you can call the rest of the API, most of which requires an interpreter context handle, so `Tcl_CreateInterp` is going to be an early call.